# How do I make the CSS grid at center of the page

Tags: css

I tried to move the grid at center of the page, I dont know why it doesn't work

I looked a lot of example, I see people using this: 
`justify-content: center;`
Even if I tried it and it doesn't work.

Here's my code

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: silver;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: none;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  padding: none;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
}

a {
  color: yellow;
}

.testing {
  padding: 150px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  /* next comment was fixed to meet syntax in a plain style sheet */
  justify-content: center;
  /* its not moving to the center of the page*/
}

.testing div {
  width: 225px;
  height: 225px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>

  <li><a href=" ">Home</a ></li>
   <li><a href="#news">News</a ></li>
   <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a ></li>
  
</ul>

     <p>hellow world</p >

 <div class = "testing">
<div></div>
```

Comment: turned your code into a snippet and fixed CSS comment to meet the plain style sheet syntaxe, so it shows live the issue you might have and can be reused and fixed or for advise in a possible answer. If that is not correct, , update the snippet with your own code. Welcome on StackOverflow.

Comment: the div with `justify-content: center;` needs to have a parent with `display: flex` to correctly work

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Box_Alignment_in_CSS_Grid_Layout#Aligning_items_on_the_Block_Axis

Answer (score 1):

The grid is centered, you just gave it 3 equal columns but only one child element, so the div is showing in the left-most column of the grid.  If you change the CSS to `grid-template-columns: 1fr` or define a [template area](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas) in the center it will display as you expected, but having only one column begs the question of why you are using a grid layout to begin with.  What kind of layout are you trying to build? Maybe a flexbox solution would better fit your needs?

Answer (score 1):

Just change `padding: 150px;` to `padding: 50%;`, on `.testing` ('testing' class).

This should work.

Best regards,

Brhaka